# getting webcam frame from 2 different computers

Tags: linux, debian, internet, streaming, real-time

I want to receive real-time recording from 2 computer webcams to my laptop via internet. I'm using Debian. Which is the simplest way?

Comment: This question is very vague. Are these security cameras? Some security cameras encrypt their images; some use formats which are not available in Linux; some only record their output onto their own dedicated component, which can be examined only via ActiveX, which again does not exist in Linux. Is the problem only one of streaming? Or do you also need recording the frames onto your pc? In which format do you have the images? Are they just in a continuously accruing file?     If all you are interested in is streaming, vlc can do that for you, both as source and as recipient.

Comment: I don't have security cameras. I have 2 webcams connected at 2 computers.

Comment: I cannot see why this question should be downvoted. I upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

You must have vlc installed from the repo, then the following command

```
  cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 :v4l2-standard= :input-slave=alsa://hw:0,0 \
  :livecaching=300 \
  :sout="#transcode{vcodec=WMV2,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=wma2,ab=128,channels=2,\
  samplerate=44100}:http{dst=:8080/stream.wmv}"
```

on each of the pcs hosting the cameras will make the stream available to the third pc. To see it, on the third pc open a browser, and type in the URL box:

```
  http://<ip_address_of_webcam_host>:8080/stream.wmv
```

or you can do it again with `vlc` instead of the Web browser, by means of

```
  vlc http://<ip_address_of_webcam_host>:8080/stream.wmv
```

again issued on the third pc, the one without the cameras.